# Dead letters encountered in Akka when routing between sibling Actors

Tags: scala, akka, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to build an agent based model where part of the model involves agents broadcasting decisions. First I initialize exactly four actors with a tracking parent, then I make them each "declare" their decisions in a specific order.

I expect each to update their parameters with each time a sibling declares its decision, but when I run the code shown below, I get logs about dead letters being encountered. How do I make sure all actors run in order, receive all declarations from siblings and do not terminate until they receive a message to declare themselves?

The main method:

```
import Member._

  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Abilene0")

  try {
    val groupMembers = Set("father", "mother", "wife", "husband")
    val group: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Group.props(groupMembers), "group")

    val father = system.actorOf(Member.props(group, generate(groupMembers)), "father")
    val mother = system.actorOf(Member.props(group, generate(groupMembers)), "mother")
    val wife = system.actorOf(Member.props(group, generate(groupMembers)), "wife")
    val husband = system.actorOf(Member.props(group, generate(groupMembers)), "husband")

    father ! Declare
    wife ! Declare
    husband ! Declare
    mother ! Declare

  } finally {
    system.terminate()
  }
```

Comment: can you paste here the dead letters log lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, its obvious that actor messages are going to delivered to `deadletters`. In your code, you are invoking `system.terminate()` in `finally` block of your try-catch-finally statement, that means, actor system termination is going to occur immediately after your try-block that will immediately stop all the actors. However, you should know that **Actors communicate using asynchronous messages**. That means, even after your try-block code completed, there can be various background task being executed in your actors until all the actors stopped.

Let me create you a scenario:

```
class Handler extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "START" =>
      println("Test Started.")
  }
}

class Tester(handler: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "TEST" =>
      println("Test started.")
      // Here, when handler actor stops when system.terminate() occur, "START" message
      // will be no longer delivered to actor handler instead delivered to deadletters.
      1 to 1000 foreach ( _ => {
        handler ! "START"
      })
  }
}

val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
val handler = system.actorOf(Props(new Handler), "handler")
val tester = system.actorOf(Props(new Tester(handler)), "tester")
try {
  tester ! "TEST"
} finally {
  system.terminate()
}
```

In above code, when `system.terminate()` is invoked, `handler` actor is stopped and then `tester` actor is stopped. However, before `tester` actor is stopped, there can be still `"START"` message being sent to `handler` actor. However, `handler` actor is already stopped, this `"START"` message will be no longer delivered to `handler` and hence delivered to `deadletters`.

Therefore, in your code, upon `system.terminate()` executed, all your actors - `group`, `father`, `mother`, `wife` and `husband` are immediately stopped and hence any further messages sent to these actors mailboxes are being delivered to synthetic actor `deadletters`.

> How do I make sure all actors run in order, receive all declarations
>   from siblings and do not terminate until they receive a message to
>   declare themselves?

For this you can pass `PoisonPill` message to each actor explicitly which will stop the actor only after all the messages in its mailbox are processed.